Issue converting aws-sdk-v2 dynamo method to aws-sdk-v3
I have a working aws-sdk-v2 method to retrieve dynamo records, and a failing v3 method. What did I do wrong when I converted the v2 method?
Error: C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\_REPOS\_PERSONAL\yyy\backend\node_modules\@aws-sdk\client-dynamodb\dist-cjs\index.js:1004 return visitor._(value.$unknown[0], value.$unknown[1]); ^ TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
Simple example of v3 code failing. I tried to make the simplest error example I could to go with the code below:
import { DynamoDBClient, QueryCommand, QueryCommandInput } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";
import { DynamoDBDocumentClient } from "@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb";

export const marshallOptions = {
    convertEmptyValues: false, // false, by default.
    removeUndefinedValues: true, // false, by default.
    convertClassInstanceToMap: true, // false, by default.
  };
  
export const unmarshallOptions = {
    wrapNumbers: false, // false, by default.
  };
(async()=>{
const dynamoDBClient = new DynamoDBClient({ region: "us-east-1" });
const dynamoDocClient = DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(dynamoDBClient, 
{
  marshallOptions,
  unmarshallOptions,
}
);

    let params:QueryCommandInput={
    TableName: 'notesV2Table',
    IndexName: 'topic-index',
    KeyConditionExpression: '#ty = :val',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: { '#ty': 'topic' },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':val': 'Dynamo' } as any
  }
  
  //return await dynamoDocClient.send(new QueryCommand(params));
  return await dynamoDBClient.send(new QueryCommand(params));

})()

Failing v3 code:
export const marshallOptions = {
    // Whether to automatically convert empty strings, blobs, and sets to `null`.
    convertEmptyValues: false, // false, by default.
    // Whether to remove undefined values while marshalling.
    removeUndefinedValues: true, // false, by default.
    // Whether to convert typeof object to map attribute.
    convertClassInstanceToMap: true, // false, by default.
  };
  
export const unmarshallOptions = {
    // Whether to return numbers as a string instead of converting them to native JavaScript numbers.
    wrapNumbers: false, // false, by default.
  };

// Create a DynamoDB client
const dynamoDBClient = new DynamoDBClient({ region: "us-east-1" });

  // Full document client
export const dynamoDocClient = DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(dynamoDBClient, {
  marshallOptions,
  unmarshallOptions,
});

export var queryNotesByTopic = async function (event: any) {
  try {
    console.log(`event`, event);
    if (event.hasOwnProperty("obj")) event = event.obj;
    console.log(`queryNotesByTopic object: `, event);
    //let topic = event.queryStringParameters["topic"] || null; //GET param

    let topic = event["topic"];
    if (!topic) throw `invalid topic ${topic}`;
    console.log(`query for each row with id: ${topic}`);

    //this matches any cards with the id 'Dynamo'
    var params = {
      TableName: TABLE_NAME,
      IndexName: "topic-index",
      KeyConditionExpression: "#ty = :val",
      ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#ty": "topic",
      },
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":val": topic,
      },
    };
    console.log(params);

    return await dynamoDocClient.send(new QueryCommand(params));
  } catch (e) {
    throw e;
  }
};

Working V2 code:
export var queryNotesByTopic = async function (event: any) {
  const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
    apiVersion: "2012-08-10",
  });
  try {
    console.log(`event`, event);
    if (event.hasOwnProperty("obj")) event = event.obj;
    console.log(`queryNotesByTopic object: `, event);
    //let topic = event.queryStringParameters["topic"] || null; //GET param

    let topic = event["topic"];
    if (!topic) throw `invalid topic ${topic}`;
    console.log(`query for each row with id: ${topic}`);

    //this matches any cards with the id 'Dynamo'
    var params = {
      TableName: TABLE_NAME,
      IndexName: "topic-index",
      KeyConditionExpression: "#ty = :val",
      ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#ty": "topic",
      },
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":val": topic,
      },
    };
    console.log(params);

    return await docClient.query(params).promise();
  } catch (e) {
    throw e;
  }
};


Does it work correctly without the marshall/unmarshall options (temporarily)?

Suspect an SDK bug, not that far removed from this one. I'd ensure your SDK is up to date and then consider raising an issue.

@jarmod no change when I removed the marshall/unmarshall options. Same error

I eventually realized the format of the params being passed into the QueryCommand was incorrect. The ExpressionAttributeValues were not getting converted correctly into dynamo json format. I solved this by manually changing the input
let params:QueryCommandInput={
TableName: 'notesV2Table',
IndexName: 'topic-index',
KeyConditionExpression: '#ty = :val',
ExpressionAttributeNames: { '#ty': 'topic' },
ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':val': {'S':'Dynamo'} } //<<<<<<<<<<<<< CORRECT
}

The last line used to be {':val':'Dynamo'} which is incorrect
or you could use lib-dynamodb which will convert the prior string JSON to dynamo
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/Package/-aws-sdk-lib-dynamodb/Class/QueryCommand/

Hmm, that would seem to suggest that docClient is not actually a Document client. See the 'Query a table' JS example here, for example, which has ":originCountry": "Ethiopia" as one of the supplied ExpressionAttributeValues.
